# RAM for dedicated MySQL server

Tags: mysql, memory

I am working on a web app that uses a remote MySQL(5.1) server (dedicated server for database). At times, web server crashes due to high CPU usage. In our application logs, there are some traces that shows there is some problem in communicating with MySQL server.

But, no errors found in MySQL logs and server was accessible from a local machine.

So, I have used mysql tuner to check if there is any problem in database configuration. The tuner result is as follows,

```
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
Please enter your MySQL administrative login: root
Please enter your MySQL administrative password: [OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.1.73
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysqld.log(304K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log exists
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysqld.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 27 warning(s).
[!!] /var/log/mysqld.log contains 188 error(s).
[--] 87 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 180115 16:07:08 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 180103 11:08:40 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 180103  7:37:06 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 180102 10:36:27 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 171109 17:10:16 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 171031  5:43:04 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 171023 10:00:56 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 171010  7:48:13 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 9) 170920  6:57:47 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 10) 170914  9:50:08 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 82 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysqld.log
[--] 1) 180115 16:06:57 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 180103 11:08:25 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 180102 10:39:22 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 171109 17:10:13 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 171031  5:42:58 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 171023 10:00:53 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 171010  7:48:11 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 8) 170920  6:57:40 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 9) 170914  9:49:38 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 10) 170804 13:23:47 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +CSV +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM 

[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 2M (Tables: 851)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 9G (Tables: 4306)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] User '@localhost' is an anonymous account.
[!!] User '@localhost' has no password set.
[!!] User 'readonly@%' has no password set.
[!!] User 'root@127.0.0.1' has no password set.
[!!] User 'root@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-x' has no password set.
[!!] User '@localhost' has user name as password.
[!!] User 'readonly@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 28d 18h 49m 49s (265M q [106.609 qps], 28M conn, TX: 485G, RX: 40G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 88% / 12%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 7.8G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 7.2G
[--] Other process memory: 147.1M
[--] Total buffers: 4.0G global + 2.7M per thread (1200 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 5.0G (64.32% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 7.2G (92.79% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (1K/265M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 31% (372/1200)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (75/28625593)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 57M selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (11K temp sorts / 3M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 58834
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (147K on disk / 58M total)
[!!] Thread cache is disabled
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (64 open / 8M opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (2/6K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (42M immediate / 42M locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.3% (1M used / 8M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/1.1M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (251M cached / 180K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 0.0% (96M cached / 542 writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 8
[!!] InnoDB File per table is not activated
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 4.0G/9.1G
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (0.244140625 %): 5.0M * 2/4.0G should be equal 25%
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (818222561475 hits/ 818225469097 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 42.33% (2251283 hits/ 5318531 total)
[!!] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (59 waits / 7569814 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server.

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mysqld.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mysqld.log file
    Remove Anonymous User accounts - there are 1 anonymous accounts.
    Set up a Password for user with the following SQL statement ( SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'SpecificDNSorIp' = PASSWORD('secure_password'); )
    Set up a Secure Password for user@host ( SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'SpecificDNSorIp' = PASSWORD('secure_password'); )
    Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Set thread_cache_size to 4 as a starting value
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64:         
    Beware that open_files_limit (6000) variable 
    should be greater than table_open_cache (64)
    Read this before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group: 
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    thread_cache_size (start at 4)
    table_open_cache (> 64)
    innodb_file_per_table=ON
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 9G) if possible.
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=512M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
    innodb_log_buffer_size (>= 1M)
```

With this result, I believe increasing `innodb_buffer_pool` will fix my problem. But, to increase this I need to increase RAM of the instance. (current RAM: 8GB, DB size: 9.1GB).

**UPDATE:**
my.cnf file

```
[client]
socket=/home/mysqldbloc/mysql.sock
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4096M
datadir=/home/mysqldbloc
socket=/home/mysqldbloc/mysql.sock
user=mysql
lower_case_table_names=1
symbolic-links=0
max_connections=1200
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log-slow-queries=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld-slow.log
```

So, how much RAM should I allocate to this instance so that there wont be any communication problem? Also, currently our web application is very slow. Will increase in RAM make it fast?

Comment: The last question looks offtopic for current site. Also, it should contain much more context information to be answerable.

Comment: Please post your complete /var/log/mysqld.log that contains 27 warning and 188 errors  AND  your complete my.cnf/ini.

Comment: @Alexei May I know what are all the information you need?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have added my.cnf file. And do you want to view the whole mysqld.log contents?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Actually, mysqld.log was last updated a month ago. But my web server has crashed more than thrice after that.

Comment: Yes, the whole log file, please. What is the size of mysqld.log?  Use of pastebin.com or dropbox or similar storage will be fine, if it will not fit here.  Also need your error log (if mysqld.log does not have the crash) covering the last of the thrice crashes, there are probably clues in it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mostly this Answer is asking for more details and making minor suggestion.  However, some of this could lead to some concrete answers after another iteration.

No, you do not necessarily need more RAM.  The buffer_pool is a *cache*.  Recently used things tend to live there; infrequently used things tend not to.

High *I/O* would be an indicator of the cache not being big enough.  But, since you are complaining about high CPU, the likely problem is inefficient queries.  This is often solved by adding a composite index or reformulating the queries.  Please find what queries are hogging the CPU, then let's discuss them.

851 MyISAM tables -- Consider migrating to InnoDB.

4306+851 tables -- Why so many?  This *may* be a sign of poor schema design.

106qps is about the median -- that is not taxing the server.

Look at the actual log file, not mysqltuner's summary.  It may indicate that you are running out of memory or something else.  (The numbers you have presented *should not* lead to out of memory.)  Is the server dedicated to MySQL, or are other memory-hogs running?

How much swap space do you have?  Was it swapping when it "crashed".  Swapping is *terrible* for MySQL performance, but it should not lead to a *crash*.

The 5M for `innodb_log_file_size` is an old default; 100M would be better.  Caution:  It is a tricky setting to change in 5.1.

Much of mysqltuner's suggestions are fake news.  But I do agree that `table_open_cache` should be increased.  Perhaps to 500.

Wilson -- I would say that a "few" `Handler_rollback` per hour is median.  So 1394 in 29 days is not remarkable.  (This is from surveying 127 disparate MySQL instances.)

An `Aborted_client` every 18 seconds -- that is high; about the 90th percentile.

I think `log_warnings=2` was new with version 5.7.  5.1 is antique; I recommend you work on upgrading before it becomes really difficult to.

**Further analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES**

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.1.73
- 8 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 29d 17:49:49
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

Increase `table_open_cache` to, say, 500.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` could be raised to 5500M if you are mostly using InnoDB and you do not have other apps running on the same server.

Raise `innodb_log_buffer_size` to 2M.

Use the slowlog to find the slow queries; then let's work on them.  Use `long_query_time=1`.
See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog for more on getting started.

Are you using a framework that does `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW COLLATIONS` 12 times a second??  What a mess.

Change to `thread_cache_size = 20`.  (0 is inefficient for Linux.)

Doing `CREATE PROCEDURE` about once a minute?  Why?  And `DROP PROCEDURE` half as often.

**Details and other observations:**

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size / _ram ) = 4096M / 8192M = 50.0%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool

`( Opened_tables ) = 8,516,944 / 2569789 = 3.3 /sec` -- Frequency of opening Tables
-- increase table_open_cache

`( table_open_cache ) = 64` -- Number of table descriptors to cache
-- Several hundred is usually good.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 4096M` -- InnoDB Data + Index cache
-- 128M (an old default) is woefully small.

`( Innodb_pages_read/Innodb_data_reads ) = 24,505,278/4361973 = 561.8%` -- Seems like these values should be equal?

`( innodb_log_buffer_size ) = 1M` -- Suggest 2MB-64MB, and at least as big as biggest blob set in transactions.
-- Adjust innodb_log_buffer_size.

`( innodb_file_per_table ) = OFF` -- Put each file in its own tablespace
-- (Mildly recommended, especially for large tables)

`( innodb_additional_mem_pool_size ) = 1M` -- (deprecated in 5.6.3, removed in 5.7.4.)
-- A high value is unnecessary.

`( innodb_stats_on_metadata ) = ON` -- Re-analyze table when touching stats.
-- ON is likely to slow down certain SHOWs and information_schema accesses.

`( local_infile ) = ON`
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

`( Created_tmp_tables ) = 60,089,656 / 2569789 = 23 /sec` -- Frequency of creating "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs.

`( Com_show_variables ) = 29,563,363 / 2569789 = 12 /sec` -- SHOW VARIABLES ...
-- Why are you requesting the VARIABLES so often?

`( Select_scan ) = 61,648,783 / 2569789 = 24 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 61,648,783 / 59135200 = 104.3%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( binlog_format ) = STATEMENT` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED. ROW is preferred; it may become the default.

`( expire_logs_days ) = 0` -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.
(Not relevant if log_bin = OFF)

`( innodb_autoinc_lock_mode ) = 1` -- Galera: desires 2 -- 2 = "interleaved"; 1 = "consecutive" is typical; 0 = "traditional".

`( log_slow_queries ) = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (Before 5.1.29, 5.6.1)

`( slow_query_log ) = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10.000000 = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Connections ) = 29,566,069 / 2569789 = 12 /sec` -- Connections
-- Increase wait_timeout; use pooling?

`( thread_cache_size ) = 0` -- How many extra processes to keep around (Not relevant when using thread pooling) (Autosized as of 5.6.8; based on max_connections)
0 is inefficient for non-Windows; 10 is probably fine. >100 may lead to OOM.

`( Threads_created / Connections ) = 29,566,068 / 29566069 = 100.0%` -- Rapidity of process creation
-- Increase thread_cache_size (non-Windows)

`( Threads_created ) = 29,566,068 / 2569789 = 12 /sec` -- Frequency of needing to create a new process.
-- Increase thread_cache_size (non-Windows)

`( thread_cache_size / max_connections ) = 0 / 1200 = 0`
-- (0 for Windows)

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_create_procedure = 0.028 /HR
Com_drop_procedure = 0.015 /HR
Com_show_collations = 12 /sec
Com_show_engine_mutex = 0.0014 /HR
Handler_read_next = 227223 /sec
Handler_read_prev = 7148 /sec
Handler_read_rnd = 12009 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd = 197,969
Innodb_log_writes / Innodb_log_write_requests = 142.3%
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Rpl_status = NULL
have_symlink = DISABLED
sql_auto_is_null = ON
```

Comment: (I added an analysis of the GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES.)

Comment: In the chat speedmy.com should have been speedemy.com.  My apologies.  Thanks for all you do in your analysis - analysis never ends.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you so much for your analysis. Will try to change the conf as per your suggestions and let you know the results. I am using an administrative tool for MySQL which executes SHOW VARIABLES whenever I connect to a database and Connection pooling is happening. Wont enabling log_slow_queries affect MySQL performance?

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani - Enabling the slowlog probably has less effect than `SHOW VARIABLES`.  The slowlog is merely appending info to a file; this info is readily available as part of the query processing.  In a large company where I worked, we simply left the slowlog turned on on all of the hundreds of servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need more than 8G of RAM.  Your DB is 9G and likely growing every working day.

Please post complete results of  ulimit -a  so we can advise to allow more than 64 tables to be open at one time to support your 300+ max_used_connections.

Suggestions for my.cfg/ini from looking at only MySQLTuner report that is posted,

```
max_connections=500  # from 1200 because < 400 used in 28d
thread_cache_size=100  # from 0 reduce threads_created count avoid OOM 
table_open_cache=8000  # from 64  to support 851 ISAM & 4306 Innodb
table_definition_cache=6000 # from ? to minimize # opens
open_files_limit=10000  # from 6K to minimize # opens
innodb_thread_concurrency=12  # from 8 to encourage concurrent activity
query_cache_limit=1K  # from default QC is not being used & keep it that way
innodb_buffer_pool_size=6G  # from 4G for 75% of RAM
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 to avoid page_cleaner overload
```

disable (with leading #) the next 4 if you have them in your config to allow defaults to work

```
sort_buffer_size
read_buffer_size
read_rnd_buffer_size
join_buffer_size
```

Normally I suggest one change a day MAX, for you, backup current conf 
go for all of them.  If any are rejected, remove for now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Before increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size, don't I need to increase the RAM of the instance? And is 6G innodb_buffer_pool enough for a 9G database?

Comment: No, these changes are needed with existing RAM.  Unless all your tables are used every day, you may find that your need for additional RAM is not really the problem.

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani  Your posted config does not have an error log named in the [mysqld] section.  Please add new dated entry with current complete my.cnf/ini after the ini that is visible.  Without it, errors have no where to go.

Comment: Your error log is probably fine with the defaults or MySQLTuner would not have found it, is my perception.
Please post complete text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
after shutdown/restart and 7 days of uptime (minimum).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73118/discussion-between-deepika-masilamani-and-wilson-hauck).

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani  Could you post complete Linux command text results of  A) ulimit -a  so we have Linux OS limits  and  B)  iostat   at a busy time to see write IOPS on your SSD.  This information will influence my.cnf/ini suggestions.

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani  In my suggestions of 2/14/2018, removed VARIABLES that are not available in 5.1.73 redhat Linux version.

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani  Looking through your STATUS & VARIABLES, A) are you aware you average an aborted_client every ~ 18 seconds?  B) are the 1394 handler_rollback events normal in 29 days?  C) are you willing to LIMIT queries / joins / sorts to 1M rows or do you expect more than 1M rows at times?  D) how many seconds do you want to allow connection to occupy resources before they have to login again?  It looks like you tolerate 8 hours with current wait_timeout=28800.  Additional suggestions will be posted after a reply to this comment, please.

Comment: A) No, I am not. Actually, we are using connection pooling and we are closing a connection when it is idle for 4 hours. I don't know why aborted client increases every 18seconds. B) I have no idea about this. How should I check this status? C) I do not need 1M rows(resultSet) at a time. In our application, mostly we have limited the results to 20, maximum limit is 100. D) 4 hours is enough. In MySQL conf, we have given wait_timeout = 28800, but in code, we are closing a connection, if it is idle for 4 hours

Comment: A) in my.cnf/ini [mysqld] section, add/change 
log_warnings=2  # from 1 to cause error log to include info about aborted_clients.  
B) top and bottom of every hour, keep a paper log of SHOW STATUS LIKE 'handler_rollback'; count with date/time until you can determine when they are likely to increase.  The rollbacks AVERAGE ~ 48 per day.  Is there a cron process every 30 minutes?  General Log for a 5 minute window to will help determine why.  C) next suggestions will include limits.  D) next suggestions will include wait_timeout=3000  # from 28800 (8 hrs) to 4 hrs + 10 minutes.

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani  Please post ulimit -a so we know what your Linux limits are.   And post complete report from iostat -x for IOPS reporting.  Identify the Device that is your SSD, please.  Then I will be better able to prepare suggestions for your my.cnf/ini .  Thanks

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani  wait_timeout will be suggested at 15000 seconds, not 3000.  My apologies.

Comment: Result of iostat: 
avg-cpu: %user %nice %system %iowait %steal %idle 
12.12 0.00 0.85 4.03 0.00 83.00 

Device: tps Blk_read/s Blk_wrtn/s Blk_read Blk_wrtn 
xvda 2.58 12.11 136.94 45988618 520244544 
xvdf 30.86 587.79 493.76 2233018362 1875776272

Comment: Result of ulimit -a: https://pastebin.com/0kupqHhy

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @WilsonHauck . Will change the conf and let you know the result.

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani  Thanks for the ulimit -a report.  ulimit -n 70000 for Linux will enable MySQL to open more than 64 limit you have been running with.   I will delay any further suggestions until you have 7 days UPTIME and please start a new Question with  the following,
current complete my.cnf/ini and php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete current text of error log 
we can get by if you STOP here, for more detailed analysis, continue please  
D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
E) ulimit -a
Thanks

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani  Any results you can share with me?  Thanks

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani Any results you can share with the community?  If any of the previous suggestions have been helpful, please upvote/accept if you have enough reputation.  Please check my profile, Network profile for contact info.  Thanks